# How to Set the Last Used On Value Manually in Programs and Features

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to figure out how (and if it is possible) I can set the `Last Used On` value for a program in Programs and Features manually.

Specifically, it's the red field in the image below. I've tried copying the format of the `Installed On` column as it is presented in the registry but that didn't set any value at all. I'm testing with Google Chrome if that makes any difference.

Nothing concrete has turned up in my search, the most I've found is that the Start Menu assisted in inferring the last use but not how this value was set or if it still can be set.

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why? The OS sets this based on the actual last time the app was used. It's an info item for the user, so that if they want to remove apps they're not using they can do so. Why would you need to artificially adjust that date?

Comment: Because as of Windows 7 the OS no longer does this to my knowledge. I'm essentially looking for a way to track software usage.

Comment: it looks like you can use applocker to audit file use. this >>> Monitor app usage with AppLocker (Windows 10) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/monitor-application-usage-with-applocker <<< says it can be done. i have not read the entire article nor have i ever tried this, so it is presented as-is. [*grin*]

Comment: That's an interesting alternative, thank you for linking that!